# I want to write one timer program that exits after 10 seconds in node js. But i am getting continuos output after 10. please correct my code

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var i=0;

var myTimer=function(){

i++;
console.log(i);

};

console.log("Timer starts \n");
setInterval(myTimer,1000);


setTimeout(function(){

console.log(" Hey! exiting the timer after 10 seconds");

clearInterval(myTimer);
},10*1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should call the `clearInterval()` on the `setInterval()` reference, not on the function called on each interval. It should look like this:

```
var function = function(){};
var intervalFunc = setInterval(function,1000);
clearInterval(intervalFunc);
```

As explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp).

**UPDATE**
As vivek doshi explained in more detail, in Your case You only need to add a reference to the timer and clear it properly:

```
var timer = setInterval(myTimer,1000);
clearInterval(timer);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer:

You need to assign the `setInterval` to a `variable` ,which can be clear with `clearInterval`

Only change in your code is this 2 lines :

```
var timer = setInterval(myTimer,1000);
clearInterval(timer);
```

---

```js
var i=0;

var myTimer=function(){

i++;
console.log(i);

};

console.log("Timer starts \n");
var timer = setInterval(myTimer,1000);


setTimeout(function(){

console.log(" Hey! exiting the timer after 10 seconds");

clearInterval(timer);
},10*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer, `setTimeout()` is actually pushing your function to be executed in the Event Queue. The time value passed is a minimum guarantee that it will execute after 10 seconds. However, if the execution thread is still not done and, there are other pending tasks in the queue, this 10 seconds delay cannot relied upon as, it can pushed further by unexecuted code.